# How can i set up IPs of AWS Classic LB to the entryPoints.web.proxyProtocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, traefik, amazon-elb

✋

As you may know, IPs for Classic Load Balancer may be changed over time. I have Traefik behind AWS ELB and I need to set IPS to entryPoints.web.proxyProtocol.

Could you please give me advice,  how to declare load-balancer IPs or CIDR range here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you change to ALB or NLB? It would be easier with them. ALB can use accelerator to get static IP, and NLB by definition has static IPs.

Comment: thanks, @Marcin for the quick response!
i solved an issue. I had to use a private ELB IP address

Answer (score 0):

with **private** ELB IP it works fine. I defined Private IPv4 CIDR